# I can not insert records php oracle - error prepare() null

Tags: php, oracle

I was adapting a mysql code to oracle but I get that error from above, I've been looking for a long time but I can not find anything that can help me.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\funcs\funcs.php:120 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\registro.php(61): registraUsuario('wae', '$2y$10$kmC83r2H...', 'wqe', 'wad@awd.cl', 0, '33fc8f862db7095...', 2) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_oracle\funcs\funcs.php on line 120
```

**conexion.php**

```
<?php

// $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","login"); //servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos

// if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
//  echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
//  exit();
// }

try //significa que intente conectar y si hay un fallo que tome el error y pase a catch
    { 
         $mysqli = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost', 'TRABAJOFINAL','TRABAJOFINAL'); 

    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        die('Error: ' .$e->GetMessage()); //getmessage es una funcion o metodo del objeto e
    }
    finally
    {
        $mysqli = null; //vacio la memoria
    }
?>
```

I have an "registro.php" archive and i added

```
require 'funcs/conexion.php';
    include 'funcs/funcs.php';
```

and it has much more code, this call function registraUsuario() in funcs.php

funcs.php has much code and it has registraUsuario()

```
function registraUsuario($usuario, $pass_hash, $nombre, $email, $activo, $token, $tipo_usuario){

        global $mysqli;

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, nombre, correo, activacion, token, id_tipo)
VALUES(:usuari, :passwor, :nombr, :corre, :activacio, :toke, :id_tip)"); // <<<<<<< LINE 120

        $stmt->bindValue(":usuari",$usuario);
        $stmt->bindValue(":passwor",$pass_hash);
        $stmt->bindValue(":nombr",$nombre);
        $stmt->bindValue(":corre",$email);
        $stmt->bindValue(":activacio",$activo);
        $stmt->bindValue(":toke",$token);
        $stmt->bindValue(":id_tip",$tipo_usuario);

        if ($stmt->execute()){
            return retornaid(); 
        }       
    }

function retornaid()
    {
        global $mysqli;

        $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sequencename.CURRVAL FROM DUAL");
        $result->execute();
        $num = $result->fetchColumn(0);

        $stmt->close();

        if($num!=0)
        {
            alert("$num");
            return $num;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I commented on line 61 that indicates the error (it does not influence the development).
If someone needs the complete codes I can send them (but the problem is in those functions that I mention "registraUsuario" specifically in "prepare()" according to the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try catch `finally` is always called, essentially nulling the connection after initialising it.

RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

> In PHP 5.5 and later, a finally block may also be specified after or
>   instead of catch blocks. Code within the finally block will always be
>   executed after the try and catch blocks, regardless of whether an
>   exception has been thrown, and before normal execution resumes.

Comment: thanks! I saw many posts with answers and none of them helped me.